# How to receive a notification to android user, when ever firebase database is updated?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an android application connected with `firebase`. When ever a new child is added to the database I need the user to be notified via a notification message. Moreover, in my application the user selects a code (eg: 71000,00100,90288) and this code is stored in shared preferences. I need the user to be notified when ever a child is added or modified, only as the code selected by the user. Any help, highly appreciated.Thank you so much in advance.

[image]

Comment: You should have a look at Cloud Functions for Firebase

Comment: As AL said, this sounds like a job for Cloud Functions. See the first use-case on this page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens

Comment: Thank you so much, AL and Frank van Puffelen !

Answer (score 1):

if your server side is firebase ,to send notification when child added , you need to create a firebase cloud function which will do that 
so this what you will do :

- create firebase cloud function
- send data with notification ( using payload )
- after receiving data in your service ( Messaging listner )check if the data ( number ) is equal to some of saved numbers in shared preferences

Answer (score 0):

On firebase, we got callbacks to provide realtime database functionalities.

Ways of doing so:

- Register a onChildAdded listener to the firebase node URL and it get triggered whenever a child is added and you can run a service that could cause notification payload which run on client side.
- use Firebase cloud functions which run on service side.

Answer (score 0):

Once i developed such application, in order to achieve this i used broadcastreceiver which was monitoring my data base for new information. (It is just suggestion) 
But u can still make use of [this](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html?m=1)  tutorial